# Php variable representation

Tags: php, variables

I have this code

```
if($pdo instanceof PDO){
    $this->last = 'lastInsertId'; 
}
else{
     $this->last = 'insert_id'; 
}
```

When i do the insert query in the datebase, how can i get the last inserted ID. I tried like this

```
$this->db->{$this->last};
```

But it did not work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to provide full code, it is not clear which class does insert operation and which tries to get the id. If $this->db is $pdo, then $this->db->last should be used, otherwise, $this->last only

Comment: no i assign instance of another DB class which uses PDO but returns instance of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastInsertId` is a method, therefore you should call it as a method, not as a property/field.

```
$this->db->{$this->last}();
```

Comment: Yep i saw that 10 minutes after i posted the question. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call-user-func)`(Array($this->db,$this->last))`